# Grey tiles appearing whenever zooming in and zooming out

Tags: tiles

We are using Mapbox on our website: https://new.raisin.digital/en/countries/united-kingdom/england/london/
For some reason, tiles appear gray first and need to be faster to load real tiles.
We've tried many options but have yet to have a better result than the one we get grey tiles appearing whenever zooming in and zooming out.

[gray tiles everywhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcstD.gif)

Do you know why? How can we solve it?

We would like to have tiles displayed more rapidly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.